# Wikipedia sound samples: vocal fry?

Tags: ipa, pronunciation, vowels

In seems to me that in Wikipedia's sound samples for the vowel sounds, there's often some vocal fry, especially in the back vowels. Vowels like [ɑ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_back_unrounded_vowel)
[æ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-open_front_unrounded_vowel)
[ä](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_central_unrounded_vowel)
[e](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) and to a lesser extent:
[ɤ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_back_unrounded_vowel)
[o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-mid_back_rounded_vowel)
[ɜ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_central_unrounded_vowel)
[œ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_rounded_vowel). Do you concur? Do you think these are good samples for understanding the vowel sounds? Is what I'm perceiving as vocal fry part of the basic vowel sounds?

Answer (score 1):

I agree, and I always recommend authoritative samples. The IPA has [a page](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/IPAcharts/inter_chart_2018/IPA_2018.html) with acknowledged masters of IPA standards – John Esling, John Wells, Jill House and Peter Ladefoged, and you should use those as reference values. This seems to be a feature of many of that person's performances, not a definitional or intrinsic property of the vowels themselves.